# Netcat: UDP connections don't terminate?

Tags: debian, osx, netcat, udp

A simple example, here's my server/host:

```
nc -ul 192.168.0.2 54
```

And the client:

```
echo "test" | nc -u 192.168.0.2 54
```

The server will intercept the "test" message, but `nc` doesn't close. It just remains open until I press Enter or Ctrl+c. Is it possible to have it terminate automatically? Or perhaps include something in the clients message to signify that the transmission has ended?

```
nc --version
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
```

I'm using Debian and macOS.

Answer (score 2):

While TCP has a concept of connections that have a beginning and an end, UDP does not have that. UDP is a *connectionless protocol*: an UDP receiver simply waits for incoming packets in a specified UDP port and outputs the content of any arriving UDP packets.

The receiving `nc` has no clue about how many packets might be incoming, nor whether those packets should all be coming in from the same host, or from several hosts: it simply receives anything that arrives to the specified UDP port and outputs the contents of the UDP packets to standard output without parsing it in any way until the `nc` process is interrupted.

There is not even any built-in guarantee that any packets sent by the client/sender are received in the same order at the receiver end: packets might be lost or reordered on the way. UDP makes no attempt to fix that: it's the job of the thing that is using UDP to deal with all those issues (or ignore them) as appropriate for its purposes.

You might decide on a specific string, make it mean "end of data" and arrange for another script at the listening end to parse the incoming data and kill the listening `nc` process when that string is received. In that way, you'll start building your own (perhaps very simple) protocol on top of UDP. *And that is exactly what UDP was designed for.*

In a nutshell, the answer to "Is it possible to have `nc -ul` terminate automatically?" is "No, unless you make something that does it."

Answer (score 1):

`netcat` has the option `-W`:

```
-W recvlimit    Terminate after receiving a number of packets
```

So:

```
nc -ulW 1 192.168.0.2 54
```

But you are using `ncat`. You can use this workaround:

```
nc -ul 192.168.0.2 54 -c 'dd count=1 bs=100000 >&3' 3>&1
```